# How to map and reduce List of Maps in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

What's a good way to map and reduce the elixir's list and convert it into new list.

Requirement: 
1. Find the maps with same id: 
2. Merge the values of "role" key (i.e. Gather all the unique values).
3. For all other maps(elements of list), do nothing.

```
list = [%{"id": 1, "role": ["A", "B"]}, %{"id": 2, "role": ["B", "C"]}, %{"id": 1, "role": ["C", "A"]} ]
```

needs to be converted in the following list:

```
ans_list = [%{"id": 1, "role": ["A", "B", "C"]}, %{"id": 2, "role": ["B", "C"]}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enum.group_by/2` to group by the `id`, then for each group, pass the `role` to `Enum.flat_map/2` and `Enum.uniq/1`:

```
list = [%{"id": 1, "role": ["A", "B"]}, %{"id": 2, "role": ["B", "C"]}, %{"id": 1, "role": ["C", "A"]} ]

list
|> Enum.group_by(&(&1.id))
|> Enum.map(fn {key, value} ->
  %{id: key, role: value |> Enum.flat_map(&(&1.role)) |> Enum.uniq}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{id: 1, role: ["A", "B", "C"]}, %{id: 2, role: ["B", "C"]}]
```

---

As requested in a comment below, here's how to preserve all key/value pairs and only modify `role` of the first item of a group:

```
list =  [%{"id": 1, "role": ["A", "B"], "somekey": "value of the key 1"},
         %{"id": 2, "role": ["B", "C"], "somekey": "value of the key 2"},
         %{"id": 1, "role": ["C", "A"], "somekey": "value of the key 3"}]

list
|> Enum.group_by(&(&1.id))
|> Enum.map(fn {_, [value | _] = values} ->
  %{value | role: values |> Enum.flat_map(&(&1.role)) |> Enum.uniq}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[%{id: 1, role: ["A", "B", "C"], somekey: "value of the key 1"},
 %{id: 2, role: ["B", "C"], somekey: "value of the key 2"}]
```

Comment: What would be a good way to get the same results when we have multiple key-value pairs!
e.g

    [%{"id": 1, "role": ["A", "B"], "somekey": "value of the key"}, %{"id": 2, "role": ["B", "C"], "somekey": "value of the key"}, %{"id": 1, "role": ["C", "A"], "somekey": "value of the key"} ]

And we don't want to change value of other keys.

Comment: What if the value of `somekey` is different for two maps with the same `id`?

Comment: Great observation.

I'm trying to get all the elements who have same id and need to shrink combine all their uniq roles. But at the same time I have few(6 actually) other key-value pairs, which should not be altered. If two records have different key-value pairs then we can just keep the one with lowest value or we can keep the key-value for first map.



I am looking at the `Enum.map_reduce` and `Enum.reduce` but struggling to figure out the  solution.

Comment: I've added a solution to keep the first map. If you want to select the map to keep using some other criteria, just pick the appropriate `value` out of `values` and use that in the `%{value | ...}` line.